# Ajax. Как получить идентификатор?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как добавить в код id, я так понимаю дело в нём, потому что редактирование происходит только после перезагрузки страницы. Спасибо)

Добавление перетаскиванием через div:

```
droppable: true, 
drop: function(event, start, allDay, delta) { 


    var title =  $.trim($(this).text());
    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event, "YYYY-MM-DD 10:00:00");
      var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event, "YYYY-MM-DD 19:00:00");


    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
    var color  = $(this).css('background-color');
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
    console.log(event);
    copiedEventObject.start = start;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
   copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css('background-color')
        copiedEventObject.borderColor     = $(this).css('border-color')
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
    console.log(start);
    $.ajax({       
        url: "add_events.php",
        data: 'title='+ title +'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&color='+ color,
        type: "POST",
          success: function(json) {
                                alert('Добавлено');
                            }
    }); 
},
```

Comment: А какая проблема возникает? Из описания вопроса трудно понять.

Comment: id чего? он должен откуда то вам приходить? совет: переучивайтесь на vanilla.js

Comment: При добавлении в календарь, запись в бд есть, но если сразу же после добавления поменять дату или время, то запись в бд не происходит, после перезагрузки страницы все ок. Несколько дней читаю про этот fullcalendar и в нескольких статьях попадалась информация что вроде как id записи нужно добавить, но к великому несчастью я не разобрался.